# Create CardView applying its cornerRadius to ImageView inside it

Tags: android, material-design, cardview

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-design-library/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/item_card.xml#L17

I tried to create a CardView with ImageView with corner Radius in Android application.

I found that when we try to set the cardCornerRadius over 0 like 12dp, it did not apply radius to the ImageView inside of the CardView.

How can I apply radius to the ImageView inside of the CardView?
Thanks for your help in advance.

[created image with app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckr3v.png)

[created image with app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVO4g.png)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
app:cardCornerRadius="12dp" // This radius is not applied to the ImageView with @id/card_image
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_image_height"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_title_height"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
        tools:text="@string/item_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
        tools:text="@string/item_desc"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/article_subheading" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_text"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Action" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cards_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cards_button_height"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:tint="@color/button_grey" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cards_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cards_button_height"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/share_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:tint="@color/button_grey" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it happening only on API < 21? If so, then it's intended - CardView doesn't clip contents on older devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

put a single view such as image view or text view inside a cardview and give it app:cardCornerRadius

Comment: Thanks. 
You mean that we need to add child CardView and put ImageView inside it right?

Yeah, I expected it would work but actually did not...
@SinaMN75